# How to use Require directive to limit file access in apache 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, permissions, access-control

I have a directory structure like the following for a website on Ubuntu 14.04, running apache 2.4.7:

```
/websites/mywebsite/index.htm
/websites/mywebsite/private.htm
/websites/myqwbsite/folder/privatefile.ext
/websites/mywebsite/folder/subfolder/publicfile.ext
```

In the Apache config for the site, I have

```
<Directory /websites/mywebsite/>
   AllowOverride Limit
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I want to use .htaccess files in the site folder such that the private.htm and privatefile.ext files are `Require all denied` but everything else is granted.

I  tried the following two .htaccess files:

/websites/mywebsite/.htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch (private.*.htm)$>
   Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

`/websites/mywebsite/folder/.htaccess`:

```
Require all denied
```

`/websites/mywebsite/folder/subfolder/.htaccess`:

```
Require all granted
```

However, apache gives a 500 - "Require not allowed here" for `/websites/mywebsite/.htaccess`

How can I make what I want happen with apache 2.4-compatible configuration (ie I do not want to load mod_access_compat and use the old style config)?

Comment: I also did a test with only the .htaccess file in `/websites/mywebsite/folder/subfolder/`.  All other .htaccess files were removed.  Apache still claims "Require not allowed here", even though apache documentation explicitly says it is allowed there: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require

Answer (score 7):

In the apache config for the site, you have to extend AllowOverride properties. Add: FileInfo and AuthConfig. Or set "AllowOverride All"

I had same problem, fixed with this config :

```
<Directory /websites/mywebsite/>
   Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig
</Directory>
```